# HTML\CSS Coupon Script

Tags: html, css, scripting

Does anyone know how to create a coupon (printable is even better) with HTML & CSS? Forgive the horribly simple question, I don't do much of any web development :)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: EDIT: Seth posted his answer again, which I accepted, thus I removed the answer from here (it was just a copy of his original deleted post).

Comment: Could you clarify what "coupon" means in this context?

Comment: A coupon like you would see in a newspaper or other print material. You know, a box with dotted lines.

Comment: /rant Why would someone down vote this? I mean, I know it is a simple question, but c'mon! What do I have to do, make it a subjective\cute\fun question? Jeeze.

Comment: I deleted it because I thought it wasn't what you were after. just undeleted it so you can check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you want

```
.coupon {
   width: 250px;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   border: 3px dashed #ccc; }

  <div class="coupon">15 points for your reputation</div>
```

around a div?  Or something more involved?

I stole it from [here](http://www.cssnewbie.com/12-creative-and-cool-uses-for-the-css-border-property/).

Comment: Yes, thank you. Surprisingly, googling css coupon gets you nothing but junk.

Comment: Glad it worked.  But now yours shows up in first page of results!  Stackoverflow FTW!

Answer (score 3):

*I'll not cover the HTML part of the question because that's very , very basic, and very specific to yourself.*

For print specific styling, in your HTML mark-up you can add a stylesheet explicitly for print media, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="my-printable-style.css"/>
```

You can also do this directly in an existing CSS doc, by using CSS directives, like so:

```
//sample ripped from http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_mediatypes.asp
@media screen
  {
  p.test {font-family:verdana,sans-serif;font-size:14px}
  }
@media print
  {
  p.test {font-family:times,serif;font-size:10px}
  }
```

but this is generally viewed as the weaker tool because it can lead to confusion and maintenance problems to bloat a single document like this, and it achieves the same as the element based method.

For a good run down of some printable CSS issues read [this list apart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).

Answer (score -3):

```
<label for="dwfrm_cart_couponCode">
                         CODE
                        </label>
<input type="text" placeholder=" CODE" name="dwfrm_cart_couponCode" id="dwfrm_cart_couponCode">
<button type="submit" value="dwfrm_cart_addCoupon" name="dwfrm_cart_addCoupon" id="add-coupon">

                        </button>
<div class="error">
                                Please Enter a Code
                            </div>
```